# Rails see what commit a capistrano deploy is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano

Is there a variable or method somewhere to see what commit a site is running? I have multiple environments and I want to be able to see one is on commit say "121asd" while another is on "313sad" for troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The current commit's hash is stored in `/app_deploy_folder/current/REVISION`, so just doing a `cat` of that file should do. If you want to see it in your local machine, you can define a capistrano task like the following:

```
desc "Show current commit's hash"
task :show_commit do
  on roles(:all) do
    within release_path do
      execute "cat #{release_path}/REVISION"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see deployed commit into the APP_FOLDER/revisions.log

This file is updated on deploy:finished step [code](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/e26503f9288e923208c1e46c35bf2c849cf92180/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L31)
More info about this file is [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/)